# TZ Portfolio Joomla gallery issue

Tags: php, joomla2.5, portfolio

I am using  the TZ Portfolio extension for Joomla 2.5.

In this extension, the image gallery option will open up a popup with more image sections. It's open in a popup, but the entire page (like the entire website opens) in the popup, and the print function starts executing (when I click on the popup the printer is also showing).

Any help or documentation URL for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check TZ Portfolio wiki http://wiki.templaza.com/Main_Page
Video tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCykS6SX6L2GOI-n3IOPfTVQ/videos